# How to show images on scroll

Tags: jquery

I want to show 3 images one bye one on scroll with fix .container

like Default "image 1"

when scroll show "image 2"

then when scroll Show "image 3"

then scroll the container This is my code.

```
<div class="container waysofcom">
        
   <div class="row imgs-row">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center text-white"><img src="img/Demo%20mockup.png" class="" width="300"><h4>Voice Call</h4></div>
      
      </div>
```

i want .container fixed until the last image show. then scroll to the next section.

Comment: have you tried any solution to make it work and failed? please add all relevant code. I would suggest search for libraries that do this instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: i think, you're looking for something [like this](http://scrollmagic.io/)

Comment: i tried that but didn't worked for mr, actually, i want to show 3 images one by one when user scroll in jquery. on first scroll show first image, on second scroll show second image. same for third image as well, and then show three image togather. Thanks in advance i hope you will understand this.

Answer (score 0):

just keep the container class div `position:relative` as it is parent

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

and keep the row class div `position:absolute` as it is child

```
.row{
  position: absolute;
}
```